# I'm trying to generate test report using ExtenetReport but when I run my demo project, then it will show me reportNG report

Tags: java, xml, ant, testng

This is my demo project:

```
public class CapturingScreenshot{
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest test;
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest
public void init()
{
    extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/ExtentScreenshot.html", true);
}

@Test
public void scenario_01()
{
    test = extent.startTest("captureScreenshot");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://autoind2.hqdev.highq.com/autoind2/LoginRequiredPage.action");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals("Autoind2", title);
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Passed");
}

@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws IOException
{
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
    {
        String screenShotPath = GetScreenShot.capture(driver, "screenShotName");
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, result.getThrowable());
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Snapshot below: " + test.addScreenCapture(screenShotPath));
    }
    extent.endTest(test);
}

@AfterTest
public void endreport()
{
    driver.close();
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
}
}
```

This file for Capture Screenshot:

```
public class GetScreenShot {

public static String capture(WebDriver driver,String screenShotName) throws IOException
{
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String dest = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\ErrorScreenshots\\"+screenShotName+".png";
    File destination = new File(dest);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, destination);        

    return dest;
}
}
```

Here is the build.xml

```
<project basedir="." default="run" name="Extends Reports">

<target name="setClassPath">
    <path id="TestAutomation.classpath">
        <fileset dir="../lib">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
</target>

<target name="start" description="Pin the Starting time of Running file">
    <tstamp>
        <format property="START_TIME" pattern="MM_dd_yyyy hh_mm_ss" locale="en_GB" />
    </tstamp>
    <echo message="Starting: ${START_TIME}" />
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="../dist/bin" />
</target>

<target name="build" description="Starting Building">
    <mkdir dir="../dist" />
    <mkdir dir="../dist/bin/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="../Reports" />
    <mkdir dir="../Reports/Logs" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="setClassPath" description="Compilation process is starting">
    <javac destdir="../dist/bin/classes" debug="true" includeantruntime="true" encoding="iso-8859-1">
        <classpath refid="TestAutomation.classpath" />
        <src>
            <pathelement location="../src/screenshot_demo_fail_testcase" />
        </src>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="../dist/" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="../">
            <include name="testng.xml" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="clean,build,compile" description="Compile project file">
    <jar jarfile="../dist/TestAutomation.jar" basedir="../dist/bin/classes" />
    <antcall target="clean" />
</target>

<path id="distclasspath">
    <fileset dir="../lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="../dist/TestAutomation.jar" />
</path>

<target name="run" depends="start,clean,build,compile,jar">
    <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="../lib/testng-6.9.9.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <testng outputdir="../Reports/Report/${START_TIME}" classpathref="distclasspath" haltonfailure="false" useDefaultListeners="false" listeners="com.ontestautomation.extentreports.listener.ExtentReporterNG">
        <xmlfileset dir="../dist/" includes="testng.xml" />
        <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="My Test Report"/>
    </testng>
</target>
```

This is my testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="screenshot_demo_fail_testcase.CapturingScreenshot" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
</listeners>

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When I run this project, it does not generate ExtentReport. Please help me solve this problem.
Here I want to run my project using ant build.xml and I want ExtentReport at the end of test.

Comment: You project works fine, seems that problem in Ant script, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Actually,  I want to create listener of ExtenetReports and use this listener I want to run this script and try to generate report